# Math explanation needed

Tags: thermodynamics, differentiation, calculus

Can someone explain to me how did they come from equation $(23)$ to $(24)$? What does the straight-line denote mean?

> and the change in energy due to the addition of matter as
>
> $$\mathrm dE_{\text{matter}}=\sum_{i=1}^m\mu_i\,\mathrm dN_i\tag{22}$$
>
> where $\mu_i$ denotes the chemical potential and $\mathrm dN_i$ denotes the change in the number of particles of species $i$ in the system. Therefore, we can write Eq. $(19)$ as
>
> $$\mathrm dN=T\,\mathrm dS-P\,\mathrm dV+\sum_{i=1}^N\mu_i\,\mathrm dN_i\tag{23}$$
>
> Considering the internal energy as a function of ($S,V,N_{i=1,...,m}$), we find
>
> $$\mathrm dE=\left.\frac{\partial E}{\partial S}\right|_{V,N_i}\mathrm dS+\left.\frac{\partial E}{\partial S}\right|_{S,N_i}\mathrm dV+\sum_{i=1}^m\left.\frac{\partial E}{\partial N_i}\right|_{S,V,N_{i\neq j}}\mathrm dN_i\tag{24}$$

Comment: The variables kept constant upon partial differentiation.

Comment: What's equation (19)? You should have included it. And please note that we use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to enter mathematical 
expressions on Physics SE, as it is the site standard. Images of text or equations 
are very strongly discouraged.

Comment: Greetings! In its current form (v1) you are asking two questions here: a question about [tag:notation] (which already has an answer) and a question about the definition of the [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) which might be a better fit for [math.se].

Answer (score 1):

It is assumed that $E$ is a function of three variables $E=E(S,V,N_i)$. The letters at the bottom of the vertical line indicate which variables are held constant when one is taking the partial derivative. An alternative notation would be to remove the vertical line, but put $(S, V, N_i)$ near $E$ everywhere. In thermodynamics the vertical line notation is more common though.

Equation (24) is simply the result of expanding of the differential of a multivariable function
$$
df(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dx_i
$$

Comment: Or round brackets $($ and $)$.

Comment: Thus eq 24 doesn't follow from eq 23, but simply from the fact that $E$ is being regarded as a function of $S$, $V$ and {$N_i$}.

Comment: See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(infinitesimal)#Differentials_as_linear_maps). It's basically the multivariable chain rule.